# will there be another world after this

Tags: allah, creation, eschatology

I know that after qiyamah the whole world will be destroyed and there will be nothing left but allah and after the day of judgment true Muslim believers and worshippers will go to heaven and the bad will go to hell but what will happen after that,

will Allah create another world.. just like he created this world?

Answer (score -1):

There cannot be such a creation as Allah promises an eternal life in the here after.

Yeah it sounds not enough for the person who has not experienced any truth. But the reality is, the rest is an eternal life. Allah has offered us eternal Life.

And brother, as u said, its not only about going to heaven or hell, but the main part is about being with and seeing Allah!

Because even in heaven there would be people who got there by the intention of enjoying the paradise alone. They may not see Allah! only few see Allah. They are called Mu'mins.

And seeing Allah is the Best joy of All. Its not just a word. Seriously, it IS the BEST ENJOYMENT ANYBODY can ever get....meaning, the enjoyment is beyond our imagination! And iam not blundering (if u r hearing this for first time). :)

Comment: I think you mis-understood his question, I think he meant, while we are in eternal life, what will Allah s.w.t do next? Will Allah s.w.t just repeat the cycle of worldly life (i.e. A new Earth but for a different people)? Or of some sort. Which to that, I'd personally say الله أعلم.